# Get Class Instance from Within Decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, decorator

I'm attempting to get my mind completely wrapped around decorators, and I had a couple neat ideas where I could use them in a reflux implementation I'm working on. I want to tag a store's class method with an action, and any time that action is generated, it knows to call any methods tagged with it.

First, I want to tag the Store method:

```
@Action
public setData(data: FakeData) {
    console.log(this);
    this.state.data = data;
}
```

then, in the action class, I want to register that method in an array:

```
class Action {
    private static methods: Method<FakeData>[] = [];

    public static register(method: Method<FakeData>) {
        this.methods.push(method);
    }

    constructor(payload: FakeData);
    constructor(store: Store, method: string);
    constructor(payload: any, method?: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) {
        if (method) {
            //TODO need actual instance of class here....
            Action.register(payload[method].bind(payload));
            return;
        }

        this.trigger(payload);
    }

    public get payload() {
        return Math.random();
    }

    private trigger(payload: FakeData) {
        Action.methods.forEach(m => m(payload));
    }
}
```

However, inside the constructor I do not have access to the actual instance of the store. I am able to get the constructor, but I'm not sure I am able to use that to achieve my goal. Perhaps instead of a constructor, I should make all stores strictly static?

I'm sure I'm not thinking about these decorators the right way, so any insight is appreciated!

[Link to full code on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Method%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09(payload%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FakeData%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20static%20methods%3A%20Method%3CFakeData%3E%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20static%20register(method%3A%20Method%3CFakeData%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.methods.push(method)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(payload%3A%20FakeData)%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(store%3A%20Store%2C%20method%3A%20string)%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(payload%3A%20any%2C%20method%3F%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3F%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09if%20(method)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%2F%2FTODO%20need%20actual%20instance%20of%20class%20here....%0D%0A%09%09%09Action.register(payload%5Bmethod%5D.bind(payload))%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09return%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09this.trigger(payload)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20get%20payload()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20Math.random()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20trigger(payload%3A%20FakeData)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09Action.methods.forEach(m%20%3D%3E%20m(payload))%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Store%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09private%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09data%3A%20%3CFakeData%3Eundefined%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20get%20data()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this.state.data%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%40Action%0D%0A%09public%20setData(data%3A%20FakeData)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(this)%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.state.data%20%3D%20data%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20s%20%3D%20new%20Store()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22Store%20before%20action%3A%20%22%2C%20s.data)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Action(%7Bname%3A%20%22TEST%22%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22Store%20after%20action%3A%20%22%2C%20s.data)%3B)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. And while it's fine to have a link to your code, you should always post your code in the question as well

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like decorators are called when the class is defined, not instantiated. This means that in order for this to work, I had to set all store methods to static, and that instances are not accessible:

```
@Action
public static setData(data: FakeData) {
    console.log(this);
    this.state.data = data;
}
```

Full working code here:

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Method%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09(payload%3A%20T)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FakeData%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20static%20methods%3A%20Method%3CFakeData%3E%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20static%20register(method%3A%20Method%3CFakeData%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.methods.push(method)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(payload%3A%20FakeData)%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(store%3A%20Store%2C%20method%3A%20string)%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(payload%3A%20any%2C%20method%3F%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3F%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09if%20(method)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%2F%2FTODO%20need%20actual%20instance%20of%20class%20here....%0D%0A%09%09%09Action.register(payload%5Bmethod%5D.bind(payload))%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09return%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09this.trigger(payload)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20get%20payload()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20Math.random()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20trigger(payload%3A%20FakeData)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09Action.methods.forEach(m%20%3D%3E%20m(payload))%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Store%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09private%20static%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09data%3A%20%3CFakeData%3Eundefined%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20static%20get%20data()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this.state.data%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%40Action%0D%0A%09public%20static%20setData(data%3A%20FakeData)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(this)%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.state.data%20%3D%20data%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22Store%20before%20action%3A%20%22%2C%20Store.data)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Action(%7Bname%3A%20%22TEST%22%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22Store%20after%20action%3A%20%22%2C%20Store.data)%3B)